# how to mock a service so as to inject it properly

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I'm trying to mock a service within a functional test, which is used by another service:

```
    $client = static::createClient();

    $stub = $this->createMock(MailService::class);
    $stub->method('sendMailToUser')->willReturn(9);
    $client->getContainer()->set('belka.auth_bundle.mail_service', $stub);
    // the *real* test should start here
```

if I try to put a `die` command inside the original `sendMailToUser`, what I get is the code stop running, although I tried to mock it by returning 9. What's wrong with it? The service I'm testing has the following declaration, then I guessed the injected service was the one wrote above:

```
belka.auth_bundle.user_handler:
    class: Belka\AuthBundle\Handler\UserHandler
    arguments:
        - '@belka.auth_bundle.user_repository'
        - '@belka.auth_bundle.mail_service'
    calls:
        - [setRequest, ["@request_stack"]]
        - [setSettings, ["@belka.auth_bundle.setting_handler"]]
        - [setBodyJsonHandler, ["@belka.container_support_bundle.body_json_handler"]]
        - [setQuantityHandler, ["@belka.container_support_bundle.quantityhandler"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I trust Symfony to create services correctly, and so I won't usually get services to then test within them (I do have a smoke-test that tries to create almost every service though).

So, if you are trying to get a 'belka.auth_bundle.user_handler', I would manually create the `Belka\AuthBundle\Handler\UserHandler` instance, with your mock as one of the arguments.

For services that are required deeper within the services, there aren't easy ways to mock them (or to get the mock into place), but you can use the service container environments to override them.

For example, I have a service that tests if a Request has come from a bot - but while running functional tests I replace it entirely with a service that always says 'not a bot', by overriding my 'app.bot_detect.detector' service in `/config/services_test.yml`

```
# set the default bot detector to a simple fake, always return false
app.bot_detect.detector:
    class: App\Services\BotDetectorNeverBot
```

In the main config/services.yml, the class would really perform the check, but the method in the test environment's `BotDetectorNeverBot` class always says false.

In the same way, you could override `belka.auth_bundle.mail_service` in services_test.yml (or config_test.yml) to not send email, and store something instead. You just have to make sure you are including '*_test.yml' files appropriately.